# Cron won't execute if am not logged in

Tags: encryption, cron

I have a cron that makes a backup of MySql, if I execute on shell it works pretty well even if I'm logged when cron supposed to execute works fine, but if I'm not logged just won't execute, I don't know what could happened, any suggestion ?

Crontab

```
00 04 * * * /home/administrador/scripts/respaldo.sh
```

respaldo.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -uroot -p[PASS] ccs < /home/administrador/scripts/limpia.sql
mysqldump -uroot -p[PASS] --routines ccs > /home/administrador/backups/backup_$(date +%Y%m%d).sql
mysqlcheck -uroot -p[PASS] --auto-repair --optimize  ccs
cd /home/administrador/backups/
tar -zcf backup_$(date +%Y%m%d).tgz backup_$(date +%Y%m%d).sql
rm backup_$(date +%Y%m%d).sql
find -name '*.tgz' -type f -mtime +90 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

respaldo.sh has execute permission

Comment: Is `/home/administrador/` an encrypted folder?

Comment: Your home directory is encrypted? That is one reason why cron jobs may fail when your user is not logged in, because your directory is only decrypted while you are logged in.

Comment: humm I don't know ... how can I check that ? Thanks for your replies

Comment: Do you have a directory like this: `/home/.ecryptfs/administrator`? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome

Comment: Yes I have `/home/.ecryptfs/administrador` directory, but I checked that on another server where cron it's working pretty well and there I have the same directory too, so both server has home directory encrypted, the same sh script and same cron but just on one of them cron are working

Comment: That was the problem `/home/administrador`directory it's encrypted so I've changed cron to another folder and to root user, so everything it's working pretty well, thanks to all for your help !

Comment: Add your solution as an answer to the ques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problema was that the `/home/adminsitrador` directory was an encrypted folder so when the user is logged in the folder it's decrypted and everything works but when the user it's logged off the folder it's encrypted and the cron can't access to that path, so I've changed the cron script and backup to another unencrypted folder and to root user and now everything it's working pretty well, thanks to all for your help !